# фильтр расширений Vcl.Dialogs.TFileOpenDialog.FileTypes пропускает не вписанное в него расширение (Delphi 11)

Tags: delphi

заношу в "фильтр" данные о расширениях, которые я хочу видеть в диалоге выбора файлов

```
const
  ext: array[0..10, 0..1] of shortstring = (
        ('TIFF Image', '*.tiff'),
        ('TIFF Image', '*.tif'),
        ('Metafiles', '*.wmf'),
        ('Enhanced Metafiles', '*.emf'),
        ('Icons', '*.ico'),
        ('PNG Image', '*.png'),
        ('GIF Images', '*.gif'),
        ('JPEG Images', '*.jpeg'),
        ('JPEG Images', '*.jpg'),
        ('Bitmaps', '*.bmp')
        );

var
  i: integer;

begin
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(CardPanel1.CardCount);
  for i := Low(ext) to High(ext) do
    with FileOpenDialog1.FileTypes.Add do
      begin
        DisplayName := ext[i, 0];
        FileMask := ext[i, 1];
      end;
```

но в каталоге с файлами есть файлик *.URL и вот он видится постоянно какой бы я ни выбрал фильтр/расширение
[image: фильтр выбран совсем другой]

как победить?

P.S. пожалуйста стандартный диалог (TOpenDialog) не предлагать

Comment: я думаю вы сами можете догадаться что нужно делать проверку после выбора файлов и желательно не по расширению а по префиксу начальных байтов файла.

Comment: это сделать не проблема, проблема в том что мне ненужно отображение данного типа файлов в показанном списке. у меня же там нет фильтра "*.*"

Comment: ссылки не открываются

Comment: FileOpenDialog разименовывает ссылки, вы можете в этом убедиться положив в каталог файл tiff и ярлык на него, и добавить файл с другим расширением и ярлык на него, в диалоге будут показаны только файл tiff и ярлык на него, т.к. они оба ссылаются на разрешенный файл tiff. Второй ярлык показан не будет. Думаю с этим вы ничего не сделаете. В опциях есть свойство `fdoNoDereferenceLinks` - но оно влияет только на возвращаемое имя, если true - то вернет имя самого lnk файла иначе то имя, которые указано в ссылке

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
у меня все норм работает..............................

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  ext: array[0..9, 0..1] of shortstring = (
        ('TIFF Image', '*.tiff'),
        ('TIFF Image', '*.tif'),
        ('Metafiles', '*.wmf'),
        ('Enhanced Metafiles', '*.emf'),
        ('Icons', '*.ico'),
        ('PNG Image', '*.png'),
        ('GIF Images', '*.gif'),
        ('JPEG Images', '*.jpeg'),
        ('JPEG Images', '*.jpg'),
        ('Bitmaps', '*.bmp'));

var
  i: integer;

begin

  for i := Low(ext) to High(ext) do
    with FileOpenDialog1.FileTypes.Add do
      begin
        DisplayName := ext[i, 0];
        FileMask := ext[i, 1];
      end;
   FileOpenDialog1.Execute
end;
```

Comment: тогда не понятно почему у меня такой беспредел твориться

Comment: вот мой exe https://github.com/dvb01/exe

Comment: смотри что выдаёт твой EXE https://ibb.co/njJHxZ7 и у меня подобная же история с моим EXE (картинка в самом вопросе вставлена)

Comment: мб с настройкой проводника у тя что то не то хкхкхк

Comment: если  TOpenDialog хорошо работает а плохо работает  TFileOpenDialog то я бы покопался в их разнице

Comment: в том то и дело, что пытаюсь найти где вообще в FileOpenDialog идёт переход к сканированию каталога и где применяется фильтр - дошёл только до просмотра сообщений (Message) от системы, по которым надо выяснить куда дальше копать... застрелиться можно